# Почему был создан список с числом элементов равным 0

Tags: c#, list, .net-core

[image: Момент с появлением ошибки]

При создании List получаю такой результат. Почему такое происходит, и как такого избежать в дальнейшем?

Comment: Пробовали поменять Count у ResultList?

Comment: @ArtikSlayer Через Capacity? Да - тот же результат

Comment: `List<>` - это вам не массив, он динамичен. Задавая в скобках при инициализации значение, вы делаете ему порог, а не сами объекты.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @EvgeniyZ за ответ в комментариях. Ниже продублирую его ответ:

> `List<>` - это вам не массив, он динамичен. Задавая в скобках при инициализации значение, вы делаете ему порог, а не сами объекты

Comment: Точнее "Число элементов, которые может вместить коллекция List<T>, прежде чем потребуется изменить ее размер." А Count показывает реальный размер списка - сколько в нём сейчас элементов.